# Handle chain of long-running callouts from Salesforce

Tags: apex, callout, isv, promises

I have seen Apex Promises, Apex libraries to chain Queueables, read about Continuations but I am still unsure what is the best solution for:

1. run multiple long-running callouts
2. Sequentially (wait for previous to complete)
3. Stop or decide on how to cope with errors

in 2021. I am looking for a solution, which is:

- as native as possible
- usable in managed packages
- somewhat scalable
- doesn't require costly add-on licenses

Answer (score 11):

Roughly speaking, this is what Queueables are for. Once Transaction Finalizers are GA, I think they'll be a pretty good solution for this.

There are many concerns, though:

- **The Queues** If you're starting batches from a trigger, you can overwhelm the flex queue pretty quickly. If you're starting Queueables, you can degrade the performance of other async processes by flooding the queue
- **Saving your progress** If you're making callouts, you'll probably need to store the progress of the overall process somewhere in SF. There's no generic answer to that
- **Too many record updates** If you keep updating the record every few seconds, this can invalidate manual updates attempted by the user and that can be a usability problem
- **The Queuable delay** After a few chained calls, you start getting time penalties before they can run again. This might or might not be acceptable
- **Error Handling** If you were to use Platform Events, this is super-hard. With BatchApexErrorEvent (packageable in Spring 21) or Transaction Finalizers, this is achievable

Today, I'd use a Batch that works like a Queueable and BatchApexErrorEvent to handle fatal errors. When Transaction Finalizers are GA and packageable, they'd be good too.

To be industrial-strength, I'd want some sort of monitoring to make sure I don't flood the queue.

**Edited to clarify the separation of queues: Thanks PhilW**

Comment: I am not interested in queueing dozens or hundreds of jobs to this queue, more like 3 to 8.

Comment: @RobertSösemann For value that small, Queueable is ideal. It should do what you want it to do in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Aiden, to be clear, as far as I'm aware, the Queueable delay is still a myth. Nobody's ever seen it in production (unless *you* have, in which case I'd like to know how you managed to do it). I know they had some talk about suicide scheduling having a 60 second penalty, Queueable with an exponential penalty, etc, but I've never seen it happen.

Comment: Until now I had the impression queueables are better future without any overarching concept on how to queue. Is there any non trivial sample code to show that.

Comment: I have certainly seen queueable delay with chained queueables - penalty goes to 60 secs after 4 links. I workaround with a counter then call to future that starts queueable chain all over

Comment: I've seen the queueable delay, @sfdcfox. I once build a solution that had to poll an external system and I was using the queueable delay to prevent the rate of polling from getting out of control. One release, the delay got much shorter and I had to rework it. So, as far as I know, the delay exists but isn't the exponential backoff that the docs claim it to be.

Comment: The other thing to note with using a queueable, when it is self-chaining, you are limited to a chain depth of 5 on non-production orgs. This is a total pain in the a**e, meaning that to allow it to function correctly on sandboxes etc. you HAVE to toggle to a future to avoid this problem. And that means you are limited on the type of state data you can pass along.

Comment: @Aidan I'm wondering why you mention the flex queue; AFAIK that's just for batches, not queueables.

Comment: Confirming cropredy's answer. The first 3 enqueues you do from an Async context fire immediately, and the 4th is roughly 60 seconds delayed, and each subsequent queueable after that is again roughly 60 seconds, indefinitely. Have chained for days and the delay remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW, you're right. I was loose with my terms there

Comment: @Aidan I don't understand those Queuables. I would expect to enque3 jobs and get a Job Id to track each laster. But instead chain members are enqueued inside the previous job. That's really a chain and not a queue. How do I get all JobIds for 5 jobs or so upfront?

Comment: I created a related question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/337060/256